# QtTextEdit: text content not rendered to QPainter

Tags: qt, qpainter, qprinter

I have difficulties rendering the context of a QTextEdit to a painter (which prints to PDF). All other widgets are correctly printed, only the **text** of the QTextWidget is not.

The widgets look fine in the GUI:

[image: QTextEdit in widget]

But the text of the QTextWidget is not printed to the PDF:

[image]

The code is quite simple. Perhaps I need to add additional flags? I would like the text to be rendered the same as it looks in the GUI, so a seperate rendering of the text (using *textField->document()->drawContents(&painter)*, is not the best solution)

```
QTextEdit* textField= ...
// textedit is correctly visible

QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
...
QPainter painter( &printer );
textField->render(&painter, QPoint(), QRegion(), QWidget::DrawChildren);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, a good solution was to directly render the *document* of the *QTextEdit* using *drawContents()*. This is even better, as it renders to vector graphics.

```
QTextEdit* textField= ...

// textedit is correctly visible
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
...

QPainter painter( &printer );
// textField->render(&painter, QPoint(), QRegion(), QWidget::DrawChildren);
textField->document()->drawContents(&painter);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code snippet. I tried:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setOutputFileName("output.pdf");
QPainter painter( &printer );
ui->textEdit->render(&painter, QPoint(), QRegion(), QWidget::DrawChildren);
}
```

And it work's. I'm using Qt 5.5.1.
[image]

You could try (as an alternative) `textEdit->print(printer);` or `painter->drawText(printer.pageRect(), ui->textEdit->toPlainText());`

Comment: Interesting :) Maybe it's a bug in Qt 4.8.2

Comment: There where some printing issues in 4.8.x. Are you using Qt under MAC?

Comment: Nope, using Windows7

Comment: Updating to 4.8.7 gives the same result, hmm, Guess I need to check Qt >5

Comment: Try: QPrinter::PrinterResolution instead of QPrinter::HighResolution. same results?

Comment: Same results. I could replicate your results in QtCreator 5.5 on Win7. In my app (Qt 4.8.2) still not showing.. Maybe it's a qss thing, or a bug in 4.8.2

Comment: It also works in 4.8.2. I guess there is something wrong in my application